# Why my PHP code is not showing on the screen?

Tags: php, jquery, web-development-server, web-deployment-project

```
<?php

    // print_r($_POST);
    $error = "";
    $successMessage = "";
    if($_POST){
        if(!$_POST["email"]){
            $error .= "An email address is required.<br>";
        }
        if(!$_POST["content"]){
            $error .= "An content address is required.<br>";
        }
        if(!$_POST["sub"]){
            $error .= "An subject address is required.<br>";
        }
        if($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ){
            $error .= "The email is invalid.<br>";
        }
        if($error != ""){
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form</strong></p>'.$error.'</div>';
        }
        else{
            $emailto = "me@mydomain.com";
            $subject = $_POST['sub'];
            $content = $_POST['content'];
            $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];
            if(mail($emailto,$sub,$content,$headers)){
                $successMessage = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Your message was sent we\'ll get back to you ASAP.</div>';
            }
            else{
                $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>Your message couldn\'t be sent please try again!</div>';
            }
        }
    }
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Get in touch!</h1>
    <div id="error"><? echo $error.$successMessage; ?></div>
    <form method="post">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="subject" class="form-label">Subject</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="sub"> 
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3 form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
  <label for="content" class="form-label">What would you like to ask us?</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" id="content" name="content" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript">

        $("form").submit(function(e){
            // e.preventDefault();
        var error = "";
        if($("#email").val() == ""){
            error += "The email field is required.<br>";
        }
        if($("#subject").val() == ""){
            error += "The subject field is required.<br>";
        }
        if($("#content").val() == ""){
            error += "The content field is required.";
        }
        if(error != ""){
        $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p><strong>There were error(s) in your form</strong></p>'+error+'</div>');
            return false;
    }
        else{
            return true;
            // $("form").unbind("submit").submit();
        }
    });
    </script> -->

    

</body>
</html>
```

I have created a simple form which contains the email, about and subject field and a submit button.When these fields are left empty,Errors should be displayed at the top of the screen but the errors are not coming.I have commented out the javascript code at the bottom which does the same work and its working but the PHP code isn't working.Can someone please help me out and find the problem in my code?

Comment: You're using short open tags when trying to echo the errors (which has been disabled as default since many PHP versions back). Try changing `<? echo` to either `<?php echo` or `<?= ` (which is short for `<?php echo`) and try again.